# jquery easyui event programmatically or by user

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

let's say I have a [jQuery EasyUI Combobox](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/combobox.php) which contains a list of data. How do I detect if a selection from that combobox has been made by the user or programmatically? I know they say that I can detect that by looking for the `event.originalEvent` but I can't seem to find that property when the user makes a selection from the combobox (or when the event has been triggered programmatically)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

if the user made the action then your element will be focused. so then you can detect it using jquery .focus() which binds an event handler to the "focus" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

to read more about it you can take a look at: 
http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: If you want you can post your code so I can help you more with it.